# How does this LED flasher circuit with just two solar cells and no batteries work?

Tags: led, solar-cell, led-driver, blink

Any thoughts on how these designs are being put together:

1. https://www.tindie.com/products/bobricius/solar-flashing-green-diamond-led-earrings-pendant/
2. https://www.tindie.com/products/bobricius/maxi-solar-flashing-red-led-pendant/

I know it's a joule thief circuit. Among the seven components used, I can identify two solar cells, one LED, one capacitor. I'm not sure what the other three ICs are. Any thoughts? I think one is a transistor, not sure which one and what part number it is.

I saw an earlier project from the author on Hackaday (https://hackaday.io/project/161017-solar-powered-flashing-led-heart-pendant) but still have not sure about the designs of (1,2.)